# Parallel indexing in Keras or Theano

Tags: python, theano, keras

**The 2D problem**

For each datapoint, I have an index matrix which I want to use to gather vectors from a 2D lookup matrix.

For a single datapoint, Theano and Keras allow easy indexing.

```
import keras.backend as K
result = K.gather(reference, indices)
```

E.g.:

```
result = K.gather(reference, indices)

#let:
indices.shape = (100, 5)
reference.shape = (101, 68)

#where:
max(indices) < reference.shape[0]

#then:
result.shape = (100, 5, 68)
```

**The 3D problem**

However, I need to repeat this process for each datapoint in a batch. E.g. I want to parallelise the lookup.

I have a 3D matrix that I want to convert into a 4D matrix.

E.g.

```
#let:
indices.shape = (batch_n, 100, 5)
reference.shape = (batch_n, 101, 68)

#desired result
result.shape = (batch_n, 100, 5, 68)
```

More formally, I am looking for an operation such that:

`result[i,j,k,:] = lookup[i, indices[i,j,k], :]`

or

`result[i,j,k,l] = lookup[i, indices[i,j,k], l]`

I implemented a Theano solution using scan. It is actually quite straightforward:

```python
import theano
import theano.tensor as T

def parallel_gather(references, indices):
    result, _ = theano.scan(fn=lambda reference, indices:reference[indices], outputs_info=None, sequences=[references, indices])
    return result
```

Rewriting this to the Keras backend seems troublesome given that `keras.rnn` is the Keras alternative. It does [not seem to support](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1584) iteration of a list of tensors, and has some weird requirements.

I also wonder if this is the fastest option, perhaps some clever reshaping could also solve the problem.